# Request External Password protected XML information and parse to my Classic ASP page

Tags: asp.net, xml, vbscript, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am in charge of Web Design and Marketing for the company I work for. I kind of got thrown into the role of Coding.

We use an eCommerce software to help with site structure and product information. This site uses Classic ASP to form all pages in order to make the process easier.

Well now I have been given an XML Data Feed instructions, but I have no idea where to begin. I have read some different posts, but none really give examples of what I am trying to do.

What I need to do is submit a request to "https://ec.synnex.com/SynnexXML/PriceAvailability" which is password protected and get the return xml.

Request sent to https://ec.synnex.com/SynnexXML/PriceAvailability using below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<priceRequest>
<customerNo>YOUR_ID</customerNo>
<userName>USERNAME</userName>
<password>PASSWORD</password>
<skuList>
<mfgPN>PRODUCTPARTNUMBER</mfgPN>
<lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
</skuList>
</priceRequest>
```

and it will return the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<priceResponse>
<customerNo>YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER</customerNo>
<userName>YOUR ID</userName>
<PriceAvailabilityList>
<mfgPN>108R00645</mfgPN>
<mfgCode>13439</mfgCode>
<status>Active</status>
<description>IMAGING UNIT, PHASER 6300/6350</description>
<GlobalProductStatusCode>Active</GlobalProductStatusCode>
<price>228.48</price>
<totalQuantity>240</totalQuantity>
<AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<warehouseInfo>
<number>3</number>
<zipcode>94538</zipcode>
<city>Fremont, CA</city>
<addr>44211 Nobel Drive</addr>
</warehouseInfo>
<qty>30</qty>
</AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<warehouseInfo>
<number>4</number>
<zipcode>30071</zipcode>
<city>Norcross, GA</city>
<addr>200 Best Friend Court, Suite# 250</addr>
</warehouseInfo>
<qty>27</qty>
</AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<warehouseInfo>
<number>5</number>
<zipcode>75081</zipcode>
<city>Richardson, TX</city>
<addr>660 N Dorothy Drive, Suite 100</addr>
</warehouseInfo>
<qty>2</qty>
</AvailabilityByWarehouse>
<lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
</PriceAvailabilityList>
</priceResponse>
```

I have no idea even where to even begin with this.

Once I get the information sent and it comes back I'm sure I can assign a Dim Value and then use the call for the value in the code I already have for displaying our products. <%=whatevervalue%>

Any help would be much appreciated.